# .net core identity server 4: Login with either username or email?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

In identity server 4, i currently have the login portion working, however it only authenticates by the username. I would like to have the choice between username or email to authenticate with.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. Need to implement IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator interface. 
This is a good reference that helped me https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs

Comment: Did you override the method? If so where?  Thanks!